# Cómo puedo hacer que mi función retorne

Tags: python, funcion

Tengo un problema con una función a la cual llamé probabilidad.

```
def Lanzamiento():
    return round(np.random.uniform(low = 0.5, high = 6.5, size = None),0)
    #como hace el man para redondear los lanzamientos 

primer_lanzamiento=Lanzamiento()
```

No sé por qué no retorna el valor de `A`, o cómo puedo cambiar la lógica de lo que he hecho para que sirva como función.

No sé si esté demasiado larga la función y deba generar algún cálculo con el `return`, pero no sabría como manejar el tema de los condicionales.

```
def probabilidad(primer_lanzamiento):
    dice = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
    one = 0
    two = 0
    three = 0
    four= 0
    five = 0
    six = 0
    for i in range(1000):# numero de simulacion
        result = random.choice(dice)
        if result == 1:
            one +=1
        elif result == 2:
            two +=1
        elif result == 3:
            three +=1
        elif result == 4:
            four +=1
        elif result == 5:
            five +=1
        elif result == 6:
            six +=1
        
    trial_result =[one,two,three,four,five,six]
    prob_trial_r=[one/1000,two/1000,three/1000,four/1000,five/1000,six/1000]
     
    if primer_lanzamiento== 2.0:
        prob=prob_trial_r[2]+prob_trial_r[3]+prob_trial_r[4]+prob_trial_r[5]
        A=print("Sumatoria de probabilidades de los numeros mayores que 2 es:", prob)
    if primer_lanzamiento== 3.0:
        prob=prob_trial_r[3]+prob_trial_r[4]+prob_trial_r[5]
        A=print("Sumatoria de probabilidades de los numeros mayores que 3 es:", prob)
    if primer_lanzamiento== 4.0:
        prob=prob_trial_r[4]+prob_trial_r[5]
        A=print("Sumatoria de probabilidades de los numeros mayores que 4 es:", prob)
    if primer_lanzamiento== 5.0:
        prob=prob_trial_r[5]
        A=print("Sumatoria de probabilidades de los numeros mayores que 5 es:", prob)        
    return A
```

Como se puede ver en la última línea, no retorna nada al ejecutar.
Estaré muy agradecido si me pueden ayudar.

Comment: Buen día, si alguna respuesta te sirvió por favor acéptala, así ayudas a otros usuarios a encontrar la solución a sus preguntas y al mismo tiempo ayudas a la comunidad a mantener abiertas únicamente las preguntas que no han sido resueltas. Lectura recomendada [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

No puedes igualar `A` a un `print()`, te va a devolver `None`

Lo que debes hacer es sustituir todas las líneas que tienes como:

```
A=print("Sumatoria de probabilidades de los numeros mayores que 5 es:", prob)
```

Por un `string` que se asigne a `A` y al hacer `return A` ya va a salir de forma correcta

```
A="Sumatoria de probabilidades de los numeros mayores que 5 es: " + str(prob)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tu código se puede reducir usando listas:

```
import random
import numpy as np

def Lanzamiento():
    return round(np.random.uniform(low=0.5, high=6.5, size=None) ,0)

def probabilidad(primer_lanzamiento):
    dice = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    lados = [0] * 6
    for i in range(1000):  # numero de simulacion
        result = random.choice(dice) - 1
        lados[result] += 1

    prob_trial_r = [x / 1000 for x in lados]

    primer = int(primer_lanzamiento) - 1
    prob = sum(prob_trial_r[primer:6])
    A = f"Sumatoria de probabilidades de los numeros mayores que {primer} es {prob}"
    print(A)
    return A

primer_lanzamiento=Lanzamiento()
probabilidad(primer_lanzamiento)
```